# AWS Data Migration Service (DMS) source engine PostgreSQL vs Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

We are migrating data from a couple of Aurora instances to our own single Aurora instance. All of them run Postgres. I realized that some of our tasks are configured to use `PostgreSQL` while others are configured to use `Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL`. Now we have not had any visible problems using either of them (with source being an Aurora instance). But I am curious on whether this can create any future problems. Does anyone have an answer on what the differences are, since I couldn't find any documentation on this.